# ZeroC Ice demo failing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ice

Note: I tried to post on their forum but was apparently not allowed so I went here.

I'm trying to get ZeroC Ice demos to work but I'm running into a problem.
I get this while trying both the C# and C++ demos.

Compiling works fine but when starting the server and client, nothing happens.
I have narrowed the cause down to the function ice_isA() which is called inside checkedCast().
When this function is called nothing happens, ie. nothing is returned and no error is raised, the debugging stops and the program does nothing.

What may be the cause of this?

This function is the first function called from the Ice library so it may as well have nothing to do with that specific function but instead something with my setup.
I run this on Windows 8 Dev Preview (essentially the same as Win 7 x64) with Visual Studio 2010 professional. The included Visual Studio 11 is uninstalled as it caused other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it was just that it didn't work well with Windows 8. A switch back to Windows 7 solved everything.